# How many samples do you need to get constant dispersion?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, computational-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $C_n$ be the hypercube $[-1,1]^n$. For $a_1,\cdots,a_s \in C_n$, define its dispersion $D(a_1,\cdots,a_s)$ as $\max_{x \in C_n}\min_{i \in [s]} \|x-a_i\|_{2}$. Let $0< \lambda < 1$ be a constant. How small can $s(n)$ be so that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{ \Pr_{a_1,\cdots,a_s \sim C_n}\left[ D(a_1,\cdots,a_{s}) \leq \lambda \right] \} \geq 2/3 \;?
$$

**Upper bound**: $O(n^{cn})$ for some constant $c$

*Proof*: Divide $C_n$ into subcubes, each with side length $l$. The number of subcubes is $\left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n$. By Coupon Collector's, if $s(n) = \left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n\log\left(\left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n \right) + K\left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n$ (for a large enough constant $K$), then all subcubes will be hit with probability at least $2/3$. If all subcubes are hit, the dispersion is at most $\frac{l\sqrt{n}}{2}$. Taking $l=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}$, we get an $O(n^{cn})$ upper bound.

**Lower bound**: $\Omega(e^{cn})$ for a constant $c$

*Proof*: Divide $C_n$ into subcubes, each with side length $l$. By Coupon Collector's, if $s(n) = \left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n \log\left(\left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n \right) + k\left(\frac{2}{l} \right)^n$ (for some small enough constant $k$), then the probability of hitting all subcubes is at most 0.6. Hence, the probability of missing at least one subcube is greater than 0.4. If you miss at least one subcube, then the dispersion is greater than $\frac{l}{2}$. Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{ \Pr_{a_1,\cdots,a_s \sim C_n}\left[ D(a_1,\cdots,a_{s}) \leq \frac{l}{2} \right] \} \leq 0.6 .
$$
Taking $l = 2\lambda$, we get an $\Omega(e^{cn})$ lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packing number of the cube with L2 balls of radius $\lambda$ is at least $ \lambda^{-n} C^n (n/2)! \approx \lambda^{-n} C^n n^{n/2} $. By the argument you had before you get the upper bound in the question is tight.

Comment: But some of the balls could be partially outside the cube. So, the "actual volumes" (volume of the ball inside the cube) of each ball is not the same. Hence, I don't see how we can apply coupon collector's. Variations of the Coupon Collector problem where coupons have different probabilities have been studied, but I don't see how we can estimate the "actual volumes" of a maximal (or "approximately" maximal) $\lambda$-ball packing.

Comment: The maximum number of $\lambda$-balls that can be "fully packed" (packed with the additional constraint that each ball is completely inside the cube) should be $(1/\lambda)^n$. We can apply coupon collector on this construction to get the $e^{cn}$ lower bound.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Regardless of whether partial or not, if you want dispersion less than $\lambda$ you need to hit every ball in the covering else the missed ball will witness large dispersion. Now the set of balls in the covering are disjoint events. So you need at least as many points to hit all of them.

Comment: That is correct, but you may not need $n^{cn}$ points sampled uniformly from the cube to hit all the (partial and full) balls. I don't see how we can apply Coupon Collector's here, since the probabilities of hitting each ball is not the same.

Comment: This is what I am not understanding. There are roughly $n^{cn}$ disjoint balls. Each new point can hit at most one of the balls (appropriately switching between $\lambda$ and $\lambda/2$ if necessary). If a ball is not hit, there is no point at distance $\lambda$ from the corresponding center, and thus the dispersion is greater than $\lambda$.

Comment: All I am seemingly using is that if you had $n$ bins and $k$ balls, you can't hit all balls if $k<n$. Furthermore, even if did care about the probabilities and the additional $\log$ factor partial balls will only decrease the probability of being it and thus would only increase the number of draws you need.

Comment: You're right! I missed that.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the packing number bound?

Comment: That was just some quick calculation using the volume bounds for the cube and the ball. Let me see if I can find an explicit reference.

Comment: Theorem 14.2 here http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec14.pdf along with standard formulas for the volumes of the balls and cubes